# In wordpress, sub-menu not displaying properly

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

See my following code. That is menu in home page,

```
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47">
<a href="http://localhost/project/service/">Service</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="http://localhost/project/services/voice/">Voice</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://localhost/project/services/data/">Data</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It showing correctly. Main Menu(service) having 2 submenu(voice & data).

Problem is, It display only last menu item only.(that is showing `data` only. no display `voice` ). See the following image,

see image in [following link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96305/sub-menu-not-displaying-properly)

If i add one more submenu means, that 3rd only displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.main-navigation ul li ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

This should fix your sub-menu.  The problem is that the list items of the sub menu were being set as inline-blocks and laying on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your submenu `ul` and submenu `li` are both inheriting width and display type styles from the top-level menu that are incorrect for the submenu.

```
.main-navigation ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

.main-navigation ul li ul {
    width: 100%
}
```